# Pause youtube and vimeo programatically and detect if a video is playing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, vimeo

I have a slider which allows video embeds ( currently by pasting in iframe code from youtube/vimeo etc). The problem I have is that the video needs to pause the slider when the user clicks the video play button and also pause the video when the slider moves to the next frame.

It seems that I will need to use the vimeo and youtube API's to get access to the information and control I want. I have looked through the API's and I think I can probably get this happening; however my problem is that from what I've seen so far the youtube API tends to work off the video ID, whereas the Vimeo API seems to work with iFrames, but I need to have a consistent input for end users in that I want to say "**Paste the video ID here**" OR "**Paste the Iframe here**" OR "**Paste the video URL here**" ... I don't want to have to ask them for an ID from youtube for one video and an Iframe from Vimeo for the next one.

I know how to manipulate the data to make the two consistent but I'd rather avoid that if at all possible. What is the best approach to get programatic access to Youtube and vimeo so that I can achieve access to play and pause and know whether a video is playing or not.

Answer (score 1):

there is a small widget on https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-video with which you can archive the things you're asking for.

You can ask the user for the video ID and render some HTML container. Then you apply the widget and can pause, play, etc. the videos with one consistent API.

Hope this helps.